# Equivalent of image/png;base64 for excel file streaming

Tags: javascript, socket.io, nodejs-server

I have been building this web app using nodejs in which i need to send the Excel file to the client over web sockets. I tried using delivery.js but i was not able to achieve the result. Then i tried socket.io-stream. There are examples for image stream. I wanted to know how i can stream excel file to the client so that they can download the file. 
If it is same as image then what should be there in place of image/png;base64

Comment: use the excel mime type.

Comment: If you Google for the keywords "excel mime type", you'll see application/vnd.ms-excel pop up for .xls and application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet pop up for .xlsx.

Comment: @AtesGoral Can you please provide some example of its usage? My code was this -  `$("#result").attr("href","data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,"+window.btoa(binaryString))` Here binaryString is the data im getting from the server.